# Rails options_from_collection_for_select display all users except current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a transfer module, where I want to **display all the possible receiver inside of an options_from_collection_select**. I managed to display all the users but I want it to not display the current user name from the selection because a user shouldn't receive his own transfer. This is what I have right now: [please click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxr0k.png). I'm currently using the ADMIN account and as you can see it appears on the select tag. I just want it to be hidden. Here's my code:

**_form.html.erb:**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <%=  f.label :administrator, "To be Receive by", class: "control-label" %>
    <%= f.select :administrator_id,options_from_collection_for_select(@administrators.order("name"), :id, :name, :selected => f.object.administrator_id),{}, class:"select2 form-control", include_blank: 'Select Receiver',required: true %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its simple did you mean except only admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

> You can access instance variable @users in your views

### Or

> You can use the scope variable given below `my explanation` of how to use

**Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :all_except, ->(user) { where.not(id: user) }
end
```

> in your `controller` access the scope variable

**controller**

```
@users = User.all_except(current_user)
```